# Поэлементное сложение списков различной длины

Tags: python, python-3.x, списки

Есть два списка:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6,7,8]
```

Нужно получить такой результат:

```
a + b = [5,7,9,7,8]
```

Надеюсь, смысл понятен.
Просто в голове одни костыли, хотелось бы найти более менее адекватное решение.

Comment: Посмотрите, что умеет zip

Comment: пожалуйста прочитайте мой ответ - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/903667/231356, я надеюсь он внесёт некоторые корректировки в предложенные логики, и вызовет дополнительную дискуссию по этому поводу))) ни на какие галочки и плюсики я не претендую))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ещё несколько вариантов решения:

```
longer = a if len(a) >= len(b) else b
c = [x+y for x,y in zip(a,b)] + longer[min(len(a), len(b)):]
```

или одной командой (менее читабельный вариант):

```
c = [x+y for x,y in zip(a,b)] + (a if len(a) >= len(b) else b)[min(len(a), len(b)):]
```

---

замеры времени выполнения для массивов длиной около `10^6`:

```
In [110]: print(len(a), len(b))
1000000 1012345

In [104]: %timeit Sergey_Gornostaev(a, b)
267 ms ± 318 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [105]: %timeit nick_gabpe(a, b)
200 ms ± 168 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [106]: %timeit AtachiShadow1(a, b)
255 ms ± 558 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [107]: %timeit AtachiShadow2(a, b)
239 ms ± 1.69 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [108]: %timeit AtachiShadow3(a, b)
200 ms ± 604 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [109]: %timeit MaxU(a, b)
124 ms ± 1.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

setup:

```
from random import randint
a = [randint(0, 10**6) for _ in range(10**6)]
b = [randint(0, 10**6) for _ in range(10**6+12345)]

print(len(a), len(b))
# 1000000 1012345

def MaxU(a, b):
    return [x+y for x,y in zip(a,b)] + (a if len(a) >= len(b) else b)[min(len(a), len(b)):]

def nick_gabpe(a, b):
    c=[]
    for x, y in zip(a,b): 
       c+=[x+y]

    if len(a) > len(b):
       c+=a[len(a)-len(b)+1:]
    elif len(a) < len(b):
       c+=b[len(b)-len(a)+1:]
    return c

def Sergey_Gornostaev(a, b):
    return [sum(i) for i in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=0)]

def AtachiShadow1(a, b):
    c = []
    la = len(a)
    lb = len(b)
    maxab = max(la, lb)
    minab = min(la, lb)
    for i in range(maxab):
        if i >= minab:
            if la < lb:
                c.append(0+b[i])
            elif la > lb:
                c.append(a[i]+0)
        else:
            c.append(a[i]+b[i])
    return c

def AtachiShadow2(a, b):
    c = []
    la = len(a)
    lb = len(b)
    maxab = max(la, lb)
    minab = min(la, lb)
    for i in range(maxab):
        try:
            c.append(a[i]+b[i])
        except IndexError:
            if la < lb:
                c.append(0+b[i])
            elif la > lb:
                c.append(a[i]+0)
    return c

def AtachiShadow3(a, b):
    c=[]
    la = len(a)
    lb = len(b)
    for x, y in zip(a,b):
       c+=[x+y]
    if la > lb:
       c+=a[la-lb+1:]
    elif la < lb:
       c+=b[lb-la+1:]
    return c
```

Comment: Это когда два списка полные, а если один будет пустой?

Comment: @AtachiShadow, добавлю когда опять доберусь до компьютера ;)

Answer (score 11):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

c = [sum(i) for i in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=0)]
```

Comment: пожалуйста прочитайте мой ответ - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/903667/231356, я надеюсь он внесёт некоторые корректировки в предложенные логики, и вызовет дополнительную дискуссию по этому поводу))) ни на какие галочки и плюсики я не претендую))

Answer (score 4):

Спасибо огромное автору за достаточно клёвую задачку, мне (как новичку) было очень интересно разобраться как это работает) сообщение длинное, но надеюсь лёгкое в прочтении))):

Предложенный в комментарии `zip` и в ответе `zip_longest` я решил оставить на последние варианты, а до них попробовать самостоятельно решить данный вопрос. И вот что я делал. Первый вариант был таким:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
c = []

for i in range(max(len(a), len(b))):
    if i >= min(len(a), len(b)):
        if len(a) == i + 1 and len(a) < len(b):
            c.append(0 + b[i])
        else:
            c.append(a[i] + 0)
    else:
        c.append(a[i] + b[i])
print(c)
```

Он, конечно же делает то, что должен. Но мне пришла вторая мысль о более логическом  (как мне казалось) решении этого цикла. Второй вариант был таким:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
c = []
for i in range(max(len(a), len(b))):
    try:
        c.append(a[i] + b[i])
    except IndexError:
        if i >= min(len(a), len(b)):
            if len(a) == i + 1 and len(a) < len(b):
                c.append(0 + bbb[i])
            else:
                c.append(a[i] + 0)
print(c)
```

С одной стороны, мне казалось, что до тех пор, пока меньший список не перестанет итерироваться, будет выполняться тело `try:`. А когда меньший список закончится, возникнет `except IndexError` и исполнится тело ошибки. Так как и этот вариант тоже делает то, что задумано, логично было бы сравнить их по скорости выполнения. Я использовал `timeit` и получил следующие результаты:

```
Вариант №1 - 8.045603216 на 1000000 (1млн) повторений
Вариант №2 - 9.076056240 на 1000000 (1млн) повторений
```

Я удивился. Я надеялся, что `try:` исключит лишнее выполнение `if` внутри цикла и тем самым ускорится. Но оказалось наоборот.
После этого, я решил сравнить свои варианты с вариантом Sergey Gornostaev, и `timeit` второй раз указал на неэффективность моих методов:

```
Вариант №1 - 8.045603216 на 1000000 (1млн) повторений
Вариант №2 - 9.076056240 на 1000000 (1млн) повторений
Sergey Gornostaev - 6.960991073 на 1000000 (1млн) повторений
```

Идея того, что на стэковерфлоу чаще всего предлагают "опытные" ответы в очередной раз подтвердилась)))) 1 секунда выигрыша у Sergey Gornostaev)) Но я подумал, стандартная библиотека == оптимизированный код. Я пошёл оптимизить свой код - в моих вариантах функции `len(), max(), min()` запускаются в каждой итерации цикла, а зачем мне 5 раз `len(a)` просить?)))) я тоже подумал что это немного тупо и надо исправить)))) вынес их в переменные до цикла и подправил логику `if`.

Вариант №1.1:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
c = []
la = len(a)
lb = len(b)
maxab = max(la, lb)
minab = min(la, lb)
for i in range(maxab):
    if i >= minab:
        if la < lb:
            c.append(0+b[i])
        elif la > lb:
            c.append(a[i]+0)
    else:
        c.append(a[i]+b[i])
print(c)
```

Вариант №2.1:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
c = []
la = len(a)
lb = len(b)
maxab = max(la, lb)
minab = min(la, lb)
for i in range(maxab):
    try:
        c.append(a[i]+b[i])
    except IndexError:
        if la < lb:
            c.append(0+b[i])
        elif la > lb:
            c.append(a[i]+0)
print(c)
```

И да, оптимизация сработала:

```
Вариант №1.1 - 4.774997384 на 1000000 (1млн) повторений
Вариант №2.1 - 5.907061396 на 1000000 (1млн) повторений
Sergey Gornostaev - 6.960991073 на 1000000 (1млн) повторений
```

Почти двукратный прирост к скорости, за счёт правильного написания кода. И оба варианта быстрее предложенной библиотеки)))

И когда я уже было хотел внести очередную правку в свой ответ, появился ответ автора:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6,7,8]
c=[]
for x, y in zip(a,b): 
   c+=[x+y]

if len(a) > len(b):
   c+=a[len(a)-len(b)+1:]
elif len(a) < len(b):
   c+=b[len(b)-len(a)+1:]
print(c)
```

И что же `timeit`? Разнёс в щепки, все предыдущие варианты))):

```
Вариант №1.1 - 4.774997384 на 1000000 (1млн) повторений
Вариант №2.1 - 5.907061396 на 1000000 (1млн) повторений
Sergey Gornostaev - 6.960991073 на 1000000 (1млн) повторений
Автор - 3.151485595 на 1000000 (1млн) повторений
```

Выигрыш 1,5 секунды перед моим "быстым" оптимизированным вариантом. Идея хорошего ответа на СО второй раз за один вопрос подтвердила себя))))))

НО! что ещё более круто в ответе самого автора, это использование `zip`. В ответе Sergey Gornostaev и в моих вариантах используется концепция большего списка, то есть, `for` будет делать столько циклов сколько элементов в большем списке - это есть ПЛОХО. Наводящий вопрос - что будет, если один из списков будет пустым? А вот что:

```
a = []
Вариант №1.1 - 4.960243867 на 1000000 (1млн) повторений
Вариант №2.1 - 7.668313717 на 1000000 (1млн) повторений
Sergey Gornostaev - 6.865756772 на 1000000 (1млн) повторений
Автор - 1.848900008 на 1000000 (1млн) повторений
```

Вот это поворот!!! Вариант №1.1 остался таким же (0.2 на погрешность). А вот Вариант №2.1 (`try except`) просто провалился - из-за того что `a = []`, каждая итерация `for` теперь приводит к `except`, что и увеличило время выполнения. Вариант Sergey Gornostaev тоже,как и 1.1 не изменился во времени исполнения (0.1 на погрешность). Но вот ответ автора показал себя в полной красе, это по круче любой "чашки сахара" (из мультика про "вот это поворот"))))) почти 3-х кратное превосходство на самым быстрым вариантом "длинного списка"!
Но это ещё не всё!))) Я же помнил `стандартная библиотека == оптимизированный код`, а код автора немножко не оптимизирован)))) функции `len(a)` и `len(b)` вызываются дважды за выполнение. Значит их можно посчитать один раз в начале и потом пользоваться переменной)):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6,7,8]
c=[]
la = len(a)
lb = len(b)
for x, y in zip(a,b):
   c+=[x+y]
if la > lb:
   c+=a[la-lb+1:]
elif la < lb:
   c+=b[lb-la+1:]
```

И вот что говорит `timeit`:

```
a = [1,2,3]:
не оптимизированный код автора - 3.138068215
оптимизированный код автора - 2.908475165

a = []:
не оптимизированный код автора - 1.909198691
оптимизированный код автора - 1.642370166
```

Выигрыш на уровне 0.25 секунды у оптимизированного кода. И это уже точное 3-х кратное превосходство над кодом "длинного списка"! Это круто))))

**P.S.**

**1.** Все измерения проводились на одном компьютере, и в приблизительно одинаковых условиях (отличия мог вносить только открытый рядом Chrome), из этого следует что отношение времени в выполнении разных логик будут другими на другом компьютере, а здесь показывается лишь **приблизительная ОТНОСИТЕЛЬНАЯ** скорость выполнения логик.

**2.** Я не профессионал, даже не любитель, `timeit` я гуглил во время написания ответа. Пока что ко мне больше применимо понятие "Script kiddie", но я учусь))))) Именно поэтому, я предполагаю, что мои исследования в этом вопрос-ответе будут содержать ошибки и не точности. И буду рад если о них мне расскажут более опытные программисты)))).

**3.** Ещё раз БОЛЬШОЕ спасибо автору вопроса-задачи и тем кто отвечал и комментировал его, мне было приятно несколько раз удивляться своей несостоятельности, и так же было приятно учиться на этом))

**4.** Приведённые измерения и отличия на 1 млн повторений могут вызвать закономерный вопрос о том, а стоит ли париться из-за таких мелких отличий, тем более что речь идёт о Python а не о C++ к примеру. И я считаю что каждый сам решит стоит ли оно того))))))) Как минимум для разминки это можно было сделать)

Comment: По-моему интереснее было бы делать замеры с длинными (1 млн. элементов) списками, чем повторять операцию миллион раз

Comment: Да, хорошее предложение)) пожалуй я так сделаю но чуть позже)

Comment: Добавил сравнение для длинных списков... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Ну и напишем свой велосипед:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6,7,8]
c=[]
for x, y in zip(a,b): 
   c+=[x+y]

if len(a) > len(b):
   c+=a[len(a)-len(b)+1:]
elif len(a) < len(b):
   c+=b[len(b)-len(a)+1:]

print(c) # [5, 7, 9, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: пожалуйста прочитайте мой ответ - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/903667/231356, я надеюсь он внесёт некоторые корректировки в предложенные логики, и вызовет дополнительную дискуссию по этому поводу))) ни на какие галочки и плюсики я не претендую))

Answer (score 1):

А вот вариант, наверное, не самый быстрый, но самый короткий:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6,7,8]
ml = min(len(a), len(b))
с = [x + y for x, y in zip(a,b)] + a[ml:] + b[ml:]
```